# XText cross-reference to rule containing a cross-reference

Tags: eclipse, xtext, cross-reference

The following is a simple representation of an xtext grammar with cross references.

There are two entities - a container and an object - and operations on each. I would like to be able to refer to an object either by it's own name, or qualified with the container name. I would like cross-references to be available in either case.

The grammar I have is:

```
Model:
    operations+=Operation*;

ContainerEntity:
    name=ID;

ObjectEntity:
    (first=[ContainerEntity] '.')? name=ID
;

Operation:
    CreateContainer | CreateObject | ContainerOp | ObjectOp
;

CreateContainer:
    'Container' container=ContainerEntity ';'
;

CreateObject:
    'Object' object=ObjectEntity ';'
;

ContainerOp:
    'ContainerOp' name=[ContainerEntity] ';'
;

ObjectOp:
    'ObjectOp' name=[ObjectEntity] ';'
;
```

And the editor statements are:

```
Container c;

Object o;

ContainerOp c;

ObjectOp o;

ObjectOp c.o; // ERROR: Couldn't resolve reference to ObjectEntity 'c'.
```

Note that it does not recognize "c" as a `ContainerEntity`. What can I do to make this work the way I described?